# Camera access with Rectangle capabilities (Objc iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I need some help with our CameraView inside our app. We have built a CameraView with Rectangle / Zoom capabilities (in a webView). When integrating this webCameraView in our app, accessing the camera does not work. Seems like we do have 2 options:

1. Make the app allow camera access from a webView *(is this still not possible 2021?)*
2. Build a copy of the webCameraView directly in the app with rectangle frame instead

[image: webCameraView with Zoom but app does not get access to the camera]

Above is what the webCameraView looks like in the app. Rectangle / Zoom is displayed, but the app does not get access to the camera.

If it is not possible to access camera directly in the app via a webView I need to go for alternative nr 2.

I will try to build the same UI via Objc in the app directly. But good updated tutorials for Objc is hard to find or being outdated. All Swift boys have taken over the town! This what I have done so far:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
 
  //-- Setup Capture Session.
    _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    //-- Creata a video device and input from that Device.  Add the input to the capture session.
    AVCaptureDevice * videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if(videoDevice == nil)
        assert(0);

    //-- Add the device to the session.
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice
                                                                        error:&error];
    if(error)
        assert(0);

    [_captureSession addInput:input];

    //-- Configure the preview layer
    _previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
    _previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    [_previewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                       self.view.frame.size.width,
                                       self.view.frame.size.height)];

    //-- Add the layer to the view that should display the camera input
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_previewLayer];
    
    
    //-- Start the camera
    [_captureSession startRunning];


    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

1. The code above gives me access to the camera
2. How do I create a dragable Rectangle / Zoom area in the middle of the screen via Objc?
3. Also With capabilities to take a photo (and the photo taken should only represent the inside-area of the rectangle-area) ?

Help!

Comment: Why would you put the camera in a web view? Definitely do it directly in the app.

Comment: This is possible via WKWebView and WebRTC in iOS 14.3+. But so far I have not been able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code you provided is for native camera control， I wonder what it has to do with webview camera?
If you want to turn on the system camera in webview and process the acquired content, you can try to look at `webrtc`. This has version restrictions, but it is open in WKWebView after iOS 14.3.

Comment: Yes, the code above is for native camera control. I need to find a good sample code making sure I can add / implement the dragable rectangle frame on the cameraView.

Comment: I also found this https://msolarana.netlify.app/2021/01/01/camera-and-microphone-in-wkwebview/ trying to make WKWebView working with WebRTC. But nothing happens when using / testing the WKWebView as web-browser in the app. Trying to understand the problem.....